# How to share global data sources when using JetBrains Gateway remote development?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, remote-development, jetbrains-gateway

I created a global data source in project A, but after switching to project B, the data source is invisible

Comment: My best suggestion/workaround right now: make it project-specific and manually copy the data source between the projects (as if they were different IDEs). Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-data-sources.html#share-data-sources-between-different-ide-instances